# Redirect non existing subdomains to 404

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I'm using GCE to set-up Virtualmin. Everything works just fine, but, here's the catch.

In the GCE DNS Zone I've pointed my domains this way:

```
example.com  A  35.234.122.118
www.example.com  A  35.234.122.118
*.example.com CNAME example.com.
```

The issue is that when I'm opening existing subdomains, everything works fine. But the problem is that I can access the root subdomain of `example.com` just by typing anything I want, for example `blabla.example.com/panel` acts like `example.com/panel`.

I'm not into DNS so much, so I'm sure there's someone out there to help me out with that.

Answer (score 0):

That wildcard alias is acting as a catch-all for your domain.

Change the wildcard CNAME entry to just `www.example.com CNAME example.com`. Then, add an individual CNAME (alias) for any other subdomain that you want to redirect to the root domain.

Comment: The problem is that my Virtualmin instance is for a freelance hosting with WHMCS, so all that stuff has to be automatic and there's no place for registering every alias manually.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrysztofiak SturdyErde is right, you either use a catchall which, as it name implies will catch any name, or you need to list the names one by one. However you probably have a catchall website in your HTTP server and you should instead generate a standard error, if each true website is defined separately in your webserver.